# In one project in firebase , I have 20 Real Time Database Apps. How can I see or monitor connections and download reports for each database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I stated in title , I have a project in which new apps (databases , say A,B,C,D...) are being created . The usual Usage tab inside Firebase , provides total connections ,download and storage use.

My problem is that I do not know which database (A or B or C or D) is consuming more or less .

Is there a way that I see usage by Database wise ?

I used the Usage tab inside Real Time Database , which gives me total of all database usage